# Supplying Multiple callback functions to .then() after promise

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, es6-promise, ecma

I was learning React and in an example the Promise API of javascript was used. the .then() function should only take one argument as a callback function, which receives the value of resolve but how is .then() taking 2 arguments as functions. Can someone please tell me how it works?

I could not understand how it works as there was always an error while trying this code. However it runs in browser.

```
//defining function getFakeMembers
const getFakeMembers = count => new Promise((resolves, rejects) => {
const api = `https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=${count}`
const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', api)
request.onload = () =>
(request.status === 200) ?
resolves(JSON.parse(request.response).results) :
reject(Error(request.statusText))
request.onerror = (err) => rejects(err)
request.send()
})
//calling function getFakeMembers
getFakeMembers(20).then(
members => log(`successfully loaded ${members.length} members`),
error => log("encountered an error loading members")
)
```

Comment: You can use the .then function two times. .then().then()

Answer (score 0):

Promises are a very powerful tool which helps you deal with asynchronous code, like the above example of a GET request.

I warmly recommend you to check this article which was very helpful for me: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

As specified in the documentation, the .then() function can 2 arguments: onFulfilled and onRejected. The second one is optional.

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

For various reasons, in my opinion, it's better to use a .catch() function in order to catch errors.